# spring webclient load balance

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-cloud-loadbalancer

Never used webclient with load balancing before and I fallowed https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-cloud-loadbalancer/ and implemented webclient load balancer, now I am trying to use helthchecks and having problem.

```
    @Bean
    @Primary
    ServiceInstanceListSupplier serviceInstanceListSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier
                .builder()
                .withRetryAwareness()
                .withHealthChecks()
                .withBase(new RestCaller("restCaller"))
                .build(ctx);
    }
```

and I got the error below

```
2021-06-27 17:32:01.562  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.564  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.606  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.606  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.607  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.607  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service httpbin.org
2021-06-27 17:32:01.607  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] o.s.c.l.core.RoundRobinLoadBalancer      : No servers available for service: restCaller
2021-06-27 17:32:01.608  WARN 12252 --- [     parallel-4] eactorLoadBalancerExchangeFilterFunction : LoadBalancer does not contain an instance for the service restCaller
```

when I comment "withHealthChecks()" everything works as expected. My main target is **to disable the "DefaultServiceInstance" in case it is failing (means http status 503 or 404 or any error).**

I prepared a reproducer at https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/web-client-loadbalancer just run "mvn test" you will see the error. you can see the configuration at https://github.com/ozkanpakdil/spring-examples/tree/master/web-client-loadbalancer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for providing the sample. Have gone through it. There are 2 issues:

1. The same `@LoadBalanced WebClient.Builder` instance is used both for handling the original request and sending health-check requests, so the calls coming out from `HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier` are done with a load-balanced `Webclient` instead of a non-load-balanced one. Since at this stage the real hosts are being used, a non-load-balanced `Webclient` instance should be used for that. You can achieve it by instantiating 2 separate `Webclient.Builder` beans in your configuration and using qualifier to pass a non-loadbalanced one to the `HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier`, like so:

   ```
    @Configuration
    @LoadBalancerClient(name = "restCaller", configuration = RestCallerConfiguration.class)
    public class WebClientConfig {

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("loadBalancedWebClientBuilder")
    WebClient.Builder loadBalancedWebClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }

    @Bean
    @Qualifier("webClientBuilder")
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder() {
        return WebClient.builder();
    }
   }

    @Configuration
    public class RestCallerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("webClientBuilder")
    WebClient.Builder webClientBuilder;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ServiceInstanceListSupplier     serviceInstanceListSupplier(ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx) {
        return ServiceInstanceListSupplier
                .builder()
                .withRetryAwareness()
                .withHealthChecks(webClientBuilder.build())
                .withBase(new RestCaller("restCaller"))
                .build(ctx);
    }
   ```
2. The `HealthCheckServiceInstanceListSupplier` sends requests at a health-check URL to verify that the service instance is alive. By default, we assume that the collaborating services have `spring-boot-starter-actuator` in their dependencies and the request is being sent at th`/actuator/health` endpoint. Since this endpoint is not configured in `httpbin`, which the tests use, we get a `404`. Changing the health-check path in properties will fix that:

   ```
    spring.cloud.loadbalancer.health-check.path.default=/
   ```

I have pushed a branch with a fixed config [here](https://github.com/OlgaMaciaszek/spring-examples/tree/fix-sc-lb-healthcheck-config). If you run the test with this setup, it passes.